# Weird behaviour with two RecyclerViews inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a ViewPager with two fragments, and each fragment has a RecyclerView. The thing is, one Recycler has been working no problem until I've added the second Recycler in the other fragment.

When I scroll in the second Recycler, the items (a cardview with an image and text) in the first recycler do something weird. Basically, the text of the cardview dissapears randomly, some items have text, some others haven't. Even the snackbar does not show up anymore.

Any idea of what's going on?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Toolbar -->
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include android:id="@+id/appbar"
                layout="@layout/aux_toolbar_main"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/left_navigation_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**main.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _initToolbar();
    _initViewPager();
    _initNavigationDrawer();
    _initAnimations();

    mBackPressed = 0;
}

private void _initViewPager()
{
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mProductsFragment    = new ProductsFragment();
    mRecommendedFragment = new RecommendedFragment();

    adapter.addFragment(mRecommendedFragment, "Fragment 2");
    adapter.addFragment(mProductsFragment, "Fragment 1");
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
    {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title)
    {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

**Fragment1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.wallakoala.wallakoala.Fragments.ProductsFragment">

    <!-- Recycler Grid -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/grid_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>

    ...

</FrameLayout>
```

**Fragment2.xml** If I scroll in this recycler, weird things happen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recommended_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recommended_grid_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>

    ...

</FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT:** Adding the two fragments code

**Fragment1.java** When weird things happen.

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // FrameLayout
    mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.frame);

    ...

    // RecyclerView
    mProductsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_recycler);

    _initRecyclerView();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void _initRecyclerView()
{
    mProductsRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mStaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mProductAdapter = new ProductsGridAdapter(getActivity()
                                , mProductsDisplayedList
                                , mFrameLayout);

    mProductsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mProductsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mStaggeredGridLayoutManager);
    mProductsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);
    mProductsRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(NUM_CACHED_PRODUCTS);
    mProductsRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
    {
        boolean scrollingUp;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {}

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            scrollingUp = dy > 0;

            if (scrollingUp)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Fragment2.java** If I scroll in this Recycler, it messes up the other

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // FrameLayout
    mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.recommended_frame);

    // RecyclerView
    mProductsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.recommended_grid_recycler);

    _initRecyclerView();
}

private void _initRecyclerView()
{
    mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);
    mProductAdapter = new RecommendedListAdapter(getActivity()
            , mProductsDisplayedList
            , mFrameLayout);

    mProductsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
    mProductsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);
    mProductsRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mProductsRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
    {
        boolean scrollingUp;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {}

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            scrollingUp = dy > 0;

            if (scrollingUp)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I don't want to fill the whole page with code, so I shall add it if some is missing.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you add the code for your recycler view and your fragments?

Comment: @user3621165 I've edited my question with the code.